# Delphi generic interfaces with string types

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, syntax-error

I tried to define a generic interface in Delphi 2010 (also in XE) and (even though it compiles) the error insight complains about the syntax. Unfortunatly this will also break the code completion for the implementing class. So I wonder if it is an error of the IDE or an error of my thoughts ;)

The interface:

```
IValue <T> = interface
  function GetValue : T;
  procedure SetValue (Value : T);
end;
```

And a implementing class :

```
TSomeClass = class (TInterfacedObject, IValue <string>, IValue <Integer>)
protected
  function GetValue1 : string;
  procedure SetValue1 (Value : string);
  function GetValue2 : Integer;
  procedure SetValue2 (Value : Integer);
  function IValue <string>.GetValue = GetValue1; //from this point error insight complains
  procedure IValue <string>.SetValue = SetValue1; 
  (*....*)
end;
```

If I substitute `string` through `Tstring` and define `TString = string` everything looks fine. Any ideas or is it a Delphi bug?

Regards,

Coco

Comment: I've reported similar issue (XE2 update 3) under QC#102293: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=102293 * IDE Fix Pack didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've observed, the IDE uses a different parser than the compiler. It has been notorious for flagging things as errors that the compiler accepts without question. I've found this especially true when generics are used. While, it has been improved with each version it still sometimes gets it wrong. A few suggestions:

1. Make sure you have the latest
   updates.
2. Open QC report (or vote for an existing one). This is more likely get addressed in XE than 2010.
3. You can try Andreas Hausladen's unofficial [IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack-2009-10/). It usually includes a number of Code Insight fixes.

You can also try [CnPack IDE Wizards](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en). It includes a feature called "Code Input Helper". It is an alternative for the IDE's builtin code completion, which in many cases still works even if Error Insight detects errors.

Comment: Thx, I have also tried in XE. Same error. IDE fix pack is installed as well as CnPack. So I will have a look at the QC of embarcadero... So you can't see anything is wrong with the code provided?

Comment: Your point 2 should read: "This is more likely to get addressed in XE2 than in any version for which you already have paid"

Comment: You are right, Deltics... This seems to be a new feature not a bug fix ;) But error-insight and code-completion in Delphi is more likely a error-inside and code-confusion :)